# How to gracefully exit this application?

Tags: .net, termination

In order to not show a form in C#.NET when first starting the application I have this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        SomethingForm frmSomething = new SomethingForm();

        Application.Run();
    }
```

It is a one form application and the `SomethingForm` is the the parent form which has a `Button` to exit which currently calls the following `Application.ExitThread();`. This button is the only way to exit the application.

Now I know this is not graceful termination, but it was the only way I could get it to work when testing. It's now causing some problems with leaving the icon in the system tray after exit.

So how do I GRACEFULLY terminate this application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply call this.Close() from the Form.  Assuming that's the only Form, the application should exit gracefully.

A slightly less graceful way is to use [Application.Exit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  The problem with this is form closing events aren't raised (fixed after .NET 1.1).

Comment: +1.  It will exit if there are no other active foreground threads.

Comment: Your Application.Exit() warning regarding form closing only applies to .NET 1.1.

Comment: I remember trying Application.Exit() before and it being temperamental about working. It seems to work regardless of what I do in my application now so that's the solution. HOWEVER this.Close() does NOT work - the form is the only form.

Comment: Thanks, that was my working understanding of how it worked and the msdn page confirmed it (didn't notice that I was set on 1.1 still).  I need to get with the times...

Answer (score 3):

or using:

```
Application.Exit()
```

anywhere in the code.

or

```
System.Environment.Exit(-1);
```

Comment: Be careful! `Environment.Exit` is a kill / terminate operation. **NOT** gracefully! You can not react on the closing-events like On_Exit().

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, you can either `Form.Close()` or `Application.Shutdown()`. You may need to change your `Application.Current.ShutdownMode` to be `Shutdown.OnLastWindowClose` or `ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose` ([MSDN Application.ShutdownMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx)).

You also mentioned that the notify icon sometimes lingers in the notification area - one possible fix for this is to call `Dispose()` on the `NotifyIcon` control to release its resources.

EDIT: My advice could be for a WPF application, it has been sometime since I have used WinForms. I hope that you (or someone else) finds it useful.